# Problem of resolution - conversion vector (points) to raster QGIS

Tags: qgis

I continue the following of the first problem :

[How to convert points to a raster in QGIS (rasterize does not show z field)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189655/how-to-convert-points-to-a-raster-in-qgis-rasterize-does-not-show-z-field)

My goal is to create outlines watershed at a resolution of 5 min (10 km) :

1. Initially I have a data as a table (.txt) : 3 columns: the geographical coordinates (x, y) and attribute (z). (See data)
2. I imported the data in QGIS then I created a vector (shapefile : see map data points) and I converted the vector to a raster (see map raster test): raster> Conversion> rasterize:  vector to raster.

[image]

My problem, I do not find a better resolution for raster map.

The data (points) on my table txt or shapefile are distributed at a resolution of 5 minutes, but QGIS does not consider this resolution, I try every time to adjust "pixel size", the best resolution found is : horizontal = 14 = vertical 14. In addition I noticed that some points are outside of pixels (see raster test).

[image]

In addition I noticed that the points are not located in the middle of pixels (see raster test).

I explained, once the raster is created, I converted to vector (polygon), and when I add the original data on these polygons, I see that there are some points that are on the outline of watershed.

My goal is to make the contours of watersheds and pixilated data is located within the basin, my goal is to get this map "desired contours).

[image]

```
x   y   z
2.05    42.5958 1
2.13334 42.5958 1
2.05    42.6792 1
2.13334 42.6792 1
1.96667 42.7625 1
2.05    42.7625 1
2.13334 42.7625 1
2.21667 42.7625 1
1.96667 42.8458 1
2.05    42.8458 1
2.13334 42.8458 1
2.21667 42.8458 1
2.3 42.8458 1
2.13334 42.9292 1
2.21667 42.9292 1
2.3 42.9292 1
2.38334 42.9292 1
2.46667 42.9292 1
2.55    42.9292 1
2.13334 43.0125 1
2.21667 43.0125 1
2.3 43.0125 1
2.38334 43.0125 1
2.46667 43.0125 1
2.55    43.0125 1
2.63334 43.0125 1
2.71667 43.0125 1
2.05    43.0958 1
2.13334 43.0958 1
2.21667 43.0958 1
2.3 43.0958 1
2.38334 43.0958 1
2.46667 43.0958 1
2.55    43.0958 1
2.63334 43.0958 1
2.71667 43.0958 1
2.8 43.0958 1
2.88334 43.0958 1
2.05    43.1792 1
2.13334 43.1792 1
2.21667 43.1792 1
2.3 43.1792 1
2.38334 43.1792 1
2.46667 43.1792 1
2.55    43.1792 1
2.63334 43.1792 1
2.71667 43.1792 1
2.8 43.1792 1
2.88334 43.1792 1
1.96667 43.2625 1
2.05    43.2625 1
2.13334 43.2625 1
2.21667 43.2625 1
2.3 43.2625 1
2.38334 43.2625 1
2.46667 43.2625 1
2.55    43.2625 1
2.63334 43.2625 1
2.71667 43.2625 1
2.8 43.2625 1
2.88334 43.2625 1
2.96667 43.2625 1
3.05    43.2625 1
3.13334 43.2625 1
3.21667 43.2625 1
1.88334 43.3458 1
1.96667 43.3458 1
2.05    43.3458 1
2.13334 43.3458 1
2.21667 43.3458 1
2.3 43.3458 1
2.38334 43.3458 1
2.46667 43.3458 1
2.55    43.3458 1
2.63334 43.3458 1
2.71667 43.3458 1
2.8 43.3458 1
2.88334 43.3458 1
2.96667 43.3458 1
3.05    43.3458 1
2.21667 43.4292 1
2.3 43.4292 1
2.55    43.4292 1
2.63334 43.4292 1
2.71667 43.4292 1
2.8 43.4292 1
3.13334 43.3458 2
3.21667 43.3458 2
2.88334 43.4292 2
2.96667 43.4292 2
3.05    43.4292 2
3.13334 43.4292 2
2.71667 43.5125 2
2.8 43.5125 2
2.88334 43.5125 2
2.96667 43.5125 2
3.05    43.5125 2
3.13334 43.5125 2
2.88334 43.5958 2
2.96667 43.5958 2
3.05    43.5958 2
3.13334 43.5958 2
2.96667 43.6792 2
3.05    43.6792 2
3.13334 43.6792 2
3.21667 43.6792 2
3.05    43.7625 2
3.13334 43.7625 2
3.21667 43.7625 2
3.13334 43.8458 2
3.21667 43.8458 2
```

Comment: follow-up (duplicate?) of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189655/how-to-convert-points-to-a-raster-in-qgis-rasterize-does-not-show-z-field

Comment: Yes it is the following of the first problem : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189655/how-to-convert-points-to-a-raster-in-qgis-rasterize-does-not-show-z-field