# Convert point layer to raster QGIS 3

Tags: raster, point, qgis-3, csv, rasterization

I have a .csv-file containing x and y-coordinates as well as different variables with attributes (var1 to var3). The csv looks like that:

[image]

Loading the data into QGIS with Add Layer → Add Delimited Text Layer then results in a point layer covering the whole world with the points lying about 1/4 degree apart from each other. Filtering by variable attributes (show only points where var1 is not NULL) gives me a point layer where each point hits some parcel of land. This looks like this (point layer over some polygon layer):

[image: Point layer over vector layer]

What I want is to **rasterize the point layer into equally sized rasters** in order to be able to calculate zonal statistics and do other operations.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I've referred to this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189655/how-to-convert-points-to-a-raster-in-qgis-rasterize-does-not-show-z-field but could not determine whether to use IDW or TIN interpolation.  How to choose which one suits my needs and which settings shall I choose? Furthermore, those tools do not allow to use my point layer. Then, I have read that I could add an header to transform the data to .ascii but the data does not seem to be in suitable format for that.

Comment: We don't know, whether TIN or IDW suits your needs, since we don't know your needs. Inform yourself on the differences between the two. Then make sure you saved your points as a shapefile and run the interpolation.

Comment: My needs are to calculate zonal statistics from the produced rasters. As can be seen in the second picture, I have a map with administrative polygon units for which I want e.g. the mean value of the variable from the table in picture 1.   I am working with EPSG4326 WGS84 as projection and I have a world map with those administrative boundaries. I guess I would choose the IDW method as I have equidistant points?!

Comment: Geographically speaking your points are equidistant, geometrically speaking they are not. Try which choice produces the "better" output.

Comment: If you load all data (incl. those with var = 0) - do you have whole rectangular area covered? If yes, you could slightly "tweak" the data structure and "convert" them to Esri ASC (ARC/INFO ASCII GRID) grid file which can also be loaded in QGIS and other tools. See this for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid

Comment: I also thought this was a good way to go. However, I am having a hard time converting the xyz columns to a z-matrix. Is there a simple solution for this step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your data points are regularly distributed (0.25 x 0.25 degrees), you can just rasterize (or "burn") to create a raster layer... you do not have to perform gridding task,

About the the linked [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189655/how-to-convert-points-to-a-raster-in-qgis-rasterize-does-not-show-z-field) in your comment, unfortunately, the interval between data points were only slightly irregular (like 0.1666 vs. 0.1667) which required to be gridded (by IDW or TIN methods).

---

**Rasterize (Vector to Raster)** tool can be found from the menu `Raster > Conversion` (or in the Processing Toolbox `GDAL > Vector Conversion`)

The interface is easy and self-explanatory.

[image]
wrong picture

[image]
revised picture

---

If you want to try gridding (IDW / TIN), my suggestion (just an opinion) is:

1. When you are interested in large structure of data ==>> TIN
2. When you want to see local variations, or find anomalies ==> IDW

Comment: I would have tried Rasterize even in the case of the lined question... I don't know but the extent (including its origin) was hard to define in that question. In your case the origin `-180, -90` (or something like that) is not hard to imagine.

Comment: Thank's for the answer! However, I always get an error message when applying the command. I first imported the csv to QGIS, converted it to a point shapefile and saved it. Then I performed the task. The error says something about Wrong value for -outsize parameter. As Output extent I used the layer extent of the point layer. Doing the task on the imported .csv also did not work..

Comment: @philsch I am terribly sorry as I inadvertently posted wrong picture, which has shown `pixel` for the output raster size units. It sets the resolution at 0.25 pixel... which makes no sense. Please choose `Georeferenced units`, so that the resolution reflects `degrees`, so that the cell size is set to `0.25 degrees`.

Comment: That does the job, thanks!